# Materializecss center inside container

Tags: css, materialize

I am using the materializecss framework: http://materializecss.com
I want to have a login form inside the middle of the container:
[image]
I already tried setting the container div to 100% but that makes it 100% + the navbar so it will add a scrollbar. This is my html how I have it now:

```
<div class="container">
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-login>
<div class="valign-wrapper full-height">
        <div class="center-block">
            <form novalidate="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
                <div class="input-field">
                    <i class="material-icons prefix">perm_identity</i>
                    <input id="username" type="text">
                    <label for="username" class="">Gebruikersnaam</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field">
                    <i class="material-icons prefix">lock</i>
                    <input id="password" type="password">
                    <label for="password">Wachtwoord</label>
                </div>
                <div class="valign-wrapper">
                    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light center-block" name="login" type="submit">
                        Inloggen
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</app-login>
</div>
```

I did see some answers on stackoverflow but those don't really make it responive and most of them are `position: absolute` which I dont want because I want it inside the container.

Comment: So If i make the container `position: relative` and then the child div absolute it will be centered inside the container?

Comment: I just tried it but the problem is that my container doesnt have its full height.

Comment: can you set the container div to 100% - the size of navbar? Also if possible make the demo on codepen or jsfiddle.

Comment: @Niraj I don't think it is possible to substract a fixed number from a percentage in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Give the div an ID.

Then, in style.css add:

```
#id {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```